# insert all in database except one in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i am working on a task where i am workking on create user. i am taking the inputs from the postman and i am validating all the fields and when ever all are validated correctly i am going to  insert it in the database.. i am using mongo  db as database. But whats the problem is i am taking inputs as first name ,lastname,userid and password and confirm password .. but when i am inserting it the connfirm password also inserting .. so i need to remove that particular field .

```
   mongo.get().collection("customers").insertOne(req.body, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
   });
```

where mongo.get() is the database connection url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can delete that property from your `document/object` before inserting into database.

Something like

```
 delete req.body.confirmPasswordFiled
 mongo.get().collection("customers").insertOne(req.body, function(err, res) {
 if (err) throw err;
 });
```